# how to draw axis inside the graph instead of rendering it outside

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

Is it possible to render the axis title and axis inside the graph as opposed to occupying space outside so that when displaying multiple graphs with the axis appearing only on the bottom axis appears to be of equal height in when using a uniform grid.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render SciChart axis across the centre of the chart in WPF:

https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-central-xaxis-and-yaxis/

This will give you a result like this:

[image]

Displaying the axis inside the chart is not possible unless you re-template the SciChartSurface control.